Syntax of vue svg inline path
I use vue-inline-svg to inline some svg's in my project.
It works fine when I call the svg like this:
<inline-svg src="/img/logo.svg" class="logo"></inline-svg>

But I have the following situation:
I have svg path's defined in the router (because they are navigational icons):
{
      path: '/:city/the-thing',
      name: 'The Thing',
      component: thingView,
      iconPath: '/img/icon-thing.svg',
 },

I' cant figure out how to write the syntax:
I write a navigation Loop:
<template v-for="value in $router.options.routes">
  <RouterLink :to="{ name: value.name, params: { city: currentCity } }">
    <img :src="value.iconPath" alt=""> // this should be the inlined svg
  </RouterLink>
</template>

I tried to write it like this:
<inline-svg :src="require(`${value.iconPath}`)"/>

and several other variations but to no avail.
Do you know the correct syntax?

you need to ensure that the src attribute of the inline-svg component is bound correctly to your dynamic path. Since you're dealing with dynamic paths defined in the router, you'll need to make sure that vue-inline-svg can handle the dynamic import properly.
Here's a full example based on your situation
    <template>
  <div>
    <template v-for="value in $router.options.routes" :key="value.name">
      <RouterLink :to="{ name: value.name, params: { city: currentCity } }">
        <inline-svg :src="require(`@/assets${value.iconPath}`)" />
      </RouterLink>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import InlineSvg from 'vue-inline-svg';

export default {
  components: {
    InlineSvg,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      currentCity: 'your-city-name', // Replace with your actual city value
    };
  },
};
</script>

Make sure that:
The SVG paths are correctly defined in your router configuration.
The SVG files are located in the correct directory relative to the project structure.
